# How would I add keys to a function type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example:

```
const myFunc = () => 'result';
myFunc.myKey = 'value';

type func = () => string;
// AND
type func = {
    myKey: string;
}
```

How would I define the type of `myFunc`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using an interface, but the property likely needs to be optional to allow for the assignment of the function, followed by the assignment of the property:

```ts
interface FuncWithMyKey {
  (): string;
  myKey?: string;
}
const myFunc: FuncWithMyKey = () => 'result';
myFunc.myKey = 'value';
```